# How to get size of filtered objectsCollection in boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I've tried the following to get the len/content_length of the `s3.Bucket.objectsCollection` in boto3 v1.7.37:

```
import boto3    
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('myBucket')
bucketObjects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='myPrefix')
if (len(bucketObjects) > 0):
     do_something()
else:
     do_something_else()
```

Unfortunately this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 's3.Bucket.objectsCollection' has no len()
```

I've also tried this with `bucketobjects.content_length` and got

```
AttributeError: 's3.Bucket.objectsCollection' object has no attribute 'content_length'
```

Am I going to have to iterate through the list and count the objects or is there a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

bucket.objects.filter() (and most other high-level boto3 calls that return collections of objects) return iterable objects that have no definite length. This is deliberate, because the potential size of the lists can be very large. To prevent your app running out of memory, they are never loaded all at once - so the size remains unknown until you actually ask for each item in turn and get to the very end.

If you know for sure the list is short, get it all with `bucketObjects = list(bucketObjects)`, but it is better not to do this. Count them by reading one at a time:

```
c=0
for b in bucketObjects: c+=1
```

(if you really need maximum efficiency, try the low-level api: `client=boto3.client('s3')` and get large chunks of the list in a few calls or if you're sure it isn't too big get the whole list at once; but this is rarely worth it)

Answer (score 12):

As Leo K said `bucket.objects.filter` returns iterable object that have no definite length. But you could limit the iteration by using the limit method. So in case you wish to check there is at list one item found you could use the following:

`results = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix_filter)
if list(results.limit(1)):
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()`

Comment: The second line, calling .limit(1) consumes a object from the filter. So if you just want to check if the filter retrieved more than one object AND want to use the first object, you have too keep in mind, that this first object is now not available any more. If you want to loop over all objects you have to either adjust your logic, or 'reset' the results object, i.e., call line 1 again.